# jQuery DataTable - How to set aoColumnDefs without creating a new DataTable object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I know how to set column names by using:

```
var table = $('#'+String(response.chartID[i])).DataTable({
                                stateSave: true,
                                aoColumnDefs: aryJSONColTable,
                                processing: true,
                                serverSide: true,
                                bDestroy: true,
                                "scrollX": true,}))
```

But is it possible to set oaColumnDef inside DataTable object?

For example on specific callbacks, I can set oaColumnDef to another set of names.

The closest I had is inside any callback, I've tried

```
$(this).dataTable().fnSettings().aoColumns
```

to get column as objects

But is it possible to set it again?

I've also tried

```
$(this).dataTable().aoColumnDefs = AnotherArray
```

However, it seems that this doesn't work.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the variable table declared above

if you want to update particular column

```
table.fnUpdate("newChangedValue", row-index , column-index);
```

if you want to update complete row

```
oTable.fnUpdate( ['column1Value', 'column2Value', 'column3Value', ... ], rowIndex );
```

to add new record

```
table.fnAddData( [  column1Value, column2Value, column3Value.... ]);
```

to get clicked row index

```
$("#tblchargeRate tbody").delegate("tr", "click", function() {
    var iPos = table.fnGetPosition( this );
});

var aData = table.fnGetData( iPos );
```

aData[0] is first column element in datatable

**Note:** take care of index value i.e first row in data table will be at 0 index

Answer (score 1):

You can updating your datatables, by the code you posted you are using a old version.

In the new version you have a column function to get the columns by selectors.

Check the [API doc](http://datatables.net/reference/api/column%28%29)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My problem is setting column, not getting column.

Comment: The problem is I might want to add more columns or decrease columns. As columns are pre-built objects, it's hard to manipulate it correctly.